# Why function messes PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have this function:

```
function errorWindow($field, $toFix)
{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('We are sorry but your request could not be logged because " . $field .
         " is not a valid response.  Please ". $toFix ." and resubmit your request')</script> <br />";

}
```

I am trying to call it from another function that is validating user input.  I'm trying to call it from this point in the function:

```
if (!$email || mb_strlen($email = trim($email)) == 0)
    $this->setError('email', 'required field');
else {
    if (!is_email($email))
        $this->setError('email', 'invalid email');
        $this->errorWindow('scriptjet@toscors2.com', 'please enter valid e-mail address');
    else
        if (mb_strlen($email) > 120)
            $this->setError('email', 'too long! 120 characters');
}
```

Keep getting an expected else error.  It doesn't matter where I place the call to the function it messes up the line underneath the call.

I can put this exact function and call in it's own file by their self and it works properly. I'm about 2 days into this issue, so starting to see the code run around the screen on me.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: No call to anything is messing up PHP. It's fuvcked up at its foundation.,

Comment: Also: that's why you should always use braces...

Comment: Like @PeeHaa said, you cant have `2 lines` of code living inside if without ***curly braces***, except it was `1 line` was break into 2 in IDE ***(Not suggested, keep using curly braces)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @PeeHaa said this is related to the arrangement of `if` / `else` statements and lack of braces.  The following code adds some braces to make sure the email error, and error window statements are executed if `is_email($email)` returns false.

```
if (!is_email($email)) {
    $this->setError('email', 'invalid email');
    $this->errorWindow('scriptjet@toscors2.com', 'please enter valid e-mail address');
}
else {
    if (mb_strlen($email) > 120)
        $this->setError('email', 'too long! 120 characters');
}
```